# Redux: How do I import the dispatch function?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to call `dispatch` in a non-component file.

My issue is that I'm trying to use redux-saga, but it is not letting me use the `yield` keyword inside of a callback function that I have to define:

```
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      yield put({ type: videoSessionActions.SEND_LOCAL_CANDIDATE, payload: event.candidate });
    }
  }
```

So what I want to do instead is using plain old `dispatch` like so:

```
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      dispatch({ type: videoSessionActions.SEND_LOCAL_CANDIDATE, payload: event.candidate })
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to `import { dispatch } from 'redux';` ?

BTW this is all happening in my generator function in my saga. The reason I am not using redux-observable is because that requires react native v0.40.0+ which I can't update yet

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are many ways to go about doing this, in [this issue](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/916) you can see how.

The main thing you have to do is `connect` your component to the store like this:

`export default connect()(Controls);` You may also provide a first argument to the `connect` function which will be the mapStateToProps function. If you do this, you will be able to do something like this outside your component (Globally)

```
let createHandlers = function(dispatch) {
  let peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
      dispatch({ type: videoSessionActions.SEND_LOCAL_CANDIDATE, payload: event.candidate })
    };
  }

  return {
    peerConnection.onicecandidate,
    // other handlers
  };
}
```

Cheers!